# Questions about polynomials in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have three questions about polynomial in linear algebra.

1. In linear algebra text (Hoffman), a polynomial over $F$ is defined as follows.

> Def. Let $F[x]$ be the subspace of $F^\infty$ spanned by by the vectors $1,x,x^2,....$ An element of $F[x]$ is called a polynomial over $F$. ($F^\infty$ is the space of functions from a set to field.)

Does it mean that $F[x]$ is a finite polynomial? This text deals it as finite but I can't admit it to be finite from the definition. Does it mean finite by the definition?

The second question is about the following which is in the text.

> If $f$ is any polynomial over $F$ we shall denote by $f^\sim$ the polynomial function from $F$ into $F$ taking each $t$ in F into $f(t)$. However, it may happen that $f^\sim = g^\sim$ for two polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that $f \neq g$. Fortunately, this unpleasant situation only occurs in the case where $F$ is a field having only a finite number of distinct elements.

2. What is difference between 'polynomial' and 'polynomial function'? I don't know why it defines the same things as different names.
3. In addition, is there any examples that $f^\sim = g^\sim$ for two polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that $f \neq g$?

Comment: I will answer (3). look at $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ over a field having two elements, $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: When talking about "span", we mean "finite linear combination". see http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Linear_span

Comment: Your definition of $\;F^\infty\;$ is incorrect: as defined in 4.1 (page 118), it is the sapce of all functions *from the set of natural numbers* (which, for some weird (to me) reason, Hoffmann&Kuntze decided to call $\;S\;$ instead of the way more usual $\;\Bbb N\;$ ) to the field $\;F\;$ . In other words, $\;F^\infty\;$ is just the set of all *sequences* of elements in $\;F\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the book at hand, but as it stand $F[x]$ is not a (finite) polynomial, it is *the set of all polynomials* with coefficients in $F$. Furthermore, the *span* of a set is the set of all *finite* linear combinations of elements from that set. So every element of $F[x]$ is a *finite* linear combination of powers of $x$, i.e. a polynomial.

For your second and third questions; for certain fields, different polynomials (i.e. different linear combinations of powers of $x$) define the same functions. For example, the constant polynomial $0$ is not the same as the polynomial $x^2+x$. But for all $c\in\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ we have $c^2+c=0$, so these polynomials take the same values on $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, and hence define the same function on $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.